# Delete the folder as soon as the .iso image is successfully generated

Tags: bash

When I create .iso(s) from multiple folders I would like that, as soon as it finishes generating the first .iso image for the folder correctly, script can immediately delete that folder from the disk

```
If folder1 ==> folder.iso
Then folder1 should be deleted
```

I use this to create iso(s) from multiple folders, I think it's not very well written

```
for p in *;
do (
    cd "$p" && for d in */;
    do
        mkisofs -allow-limited-size -l -J -r -l -iso-level 3 -o "${d%/}.iso" "$d";
    done
);
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure about `mkisofs` return statuses but if it implements them correctly then you could do `mkisofs ... && rm -rf "$d"`

Comment: Should be written `for p in *; do (cd "$p" && for d in */; do mkisofs -allow-limited-size -l -J -r -l -iso-level 3 -o "${d%/}.iso" "$d" && rm -rf "$d"; done); done` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution of Fravadona

```
for p in *;
do (
    cd "$p" && for d in */;
    do
        mkisofs -allow-limited-size -l -J -r -l -iso-level 3 -o "${d%/}.iso" "$d" && rm -rf "$d";
    done
);
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).